# spy on method call in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jestjs, enzyme

I want to test some custom methods that get called in the componentDidMount life cycle method of a React component.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    getData().then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.setState({
        rate: res.data.bpi.USD.rate_float
      });
    });
  }
```

I am importing the getData method from api.js:

```
export const getData = () => {
  return axios
    .get("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json")
    .then(res => {
      return res;
    });
};
```

Testing it with Jest and Enyzme like this:

```
describe("App", () => {
  describe("Calls getData when componentDidMount", () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(App.prototype, "getData");
    const wrapper = mount(<App {...props} />);
    wrapper.instance().getData();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled(1);
  });
});
```

It fails: `App › Calls getData when componentDidMount › encountered a declaration exception`

And give me the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_isMockFunction' of undefined
```

What are I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is getData and where is it defined? `getData()` - that's not App method.

Comment: @estus I am importing it from antoher file. If I am importing it from another file, how do I test it?

Comment: Can you show this in the question? Code-related questions should contain https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Then you cannot spy on it on App.prototype. Because it's not a method. Most likely this should be done with `jest.mock`.

Comment: @estus updated the question.

Comment: Try placing `const spy` beneath `const wrapper`. Instead of `App.prototype` try `wrapper.instance()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getData` is not `App` method, it cannot be spied on `App` class, it is not available on `wrapper.instance()` component instance.

Modules can be mocked with `jest.mock`. Proper unit testing requires to mock everything but tested unit. `axios` request can be mocked with:

```
import { getData } from '.../api';

jest.mock('.../api');

describe("App", () => {
  describe("Calls getData when componentDidMount", () => {
    getData.mockResolvedValue({ data: ... });
    const wrapper = mount(<App {...props} />);
    expect(getData).toHaveBeenCalled(1);
  });
});
```

Notice that `shallow` [enables lifecycle hooks by default](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html), it's expected that `componentDidMount` is called on component instantiation.

`getData` can be tested in similar way by mocking `axios`; [this is shown in the manual](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mocking-modules).